# SharePoint 2013 People Search results returns incorrect links

Tags: my-site

We are having some issue with people search in our SharePoint 2013 farm. Actually we have a SharePoint 2013 farm which is crawling user Mysite data's from different SharePoint 2007 farm. We don't see any issue with Mysite crawling and in crawl logs everything shows success status with the entries like `http:// mysiteurl:80/Person.aspx?guid=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`.

When we do the people search in our search center site it returns the results but while clicking the results it ends with the error message "Could not load a user profile" and we are seeing results URL has the characters **"%252D"** for the places having hyphens "-". We have confirmed that our search index contains **"%2D"** characters only but in search results we are receiving "%252D". We doubt error may be due to display templates or something else. We are running with SP 2013 SP1 + June'14 CU.

Does anyone have this issue? I’m looking for some resolution on this issue.
Any ideas?

Comment: We are also facing the same issue with similar setup, are you able to find the solution for this? MKP

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't found the solution yet...
The issue has been resolved in CU September 2014.